# How I can insert a list of values into a new column of the already existing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have some text values:

```
( 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' )
```

And I have a table:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'some value' | 'some value' |
| 'some value' | 'some value' |
| 'some value' | 'some value' |

I need, that my table looking like this:

| Column 1 | Column2 | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'some value' | 'some value' | 'apple' |
| 'some value' | 'some value' | 'orange' |
| 'some value' | 'some value' | 'banana' |

How can I do this?

I found only solutions, that can fill `New Column` with only one default value, random values and sequences like `(1,2,3,4,5)`, but it isn't what I looking for.

Comment: **a** "I have some text values" in what form? a table? an array? **b** Does your existing table really have just "some value" (i.e. the same value) in all rows in both columns? **c** Is the number of "text values" equal to the number of rows in the existing table?

Comment: **a** In simple text form. I just write in notepad three words: `'apple', 'orange', 'banana'`, and I want this three words in my new column. **b** No, every of the `'some value'` is different. **c** Yes, it equal.

Comment: Is there a unique key for the table into which the new values are being inserted?

Comment: so why not just write an update query?  ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD COLUMN new_column varchar;

UPDATE my_table
SET new_column = CASE
  WHEN column1 = '1stvalue' THEN 'apple'
  WHEN column1 = '2ndvalue' THEN 'orange'
  WHEN column1 = '3rd value' THEN 'banana'
  ELSE NULL
END;

Comment: The key to all this is what determines how new values match up. You need to explain that part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach that might satisfy your requirements:

```
UPDATE some_table
  SET column3 = new_values.column3
  FROM (SELECT column1,
               column2,
               ('{apple, orange, banana}'::text[])[row_number() OVER (ORDER BY column1, column2)] AS column3
          FROM some_table) new_values
  WHERE some_table.column1 = new_values.column1
    AND some_table.column2 = new_values.column2;
```

This approach can easily be modified to cycle through the new column values until all of `some_table`'s rows have a value in the new column by doing the following:

```
WITH t(value_list) AS (
  VALUES ('{apple, orange, banana}'::text[]))
UPDATE some_table
  SET column3 = new_values.column3
  FROM (SELECT column1,
               column2,
               t.value_list[(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY column1, column2) - 1) % array_length(t.value_list, 1) + 1] AS column3
          FROM some_table CROSS JOIN t) new_values
  WHERE some_table.column1 = new_values.column1
    AND some_table.column2 = new_values.column2;
```